# Why don't we use free(node) when inserting in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, singly-linked-list

```
void push(struct node **head, int data)
{
        struct node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->data = data;
        newnode->next = *head;
        *head=newnode;

}
```

I came across this function, I wonder why didn't we use free(newnode) since we affected its value to *head and we no longer have use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will free the node pointed to by the pointer `newnode` then as a result the pointer `*head` due to this statement

```
*head=newnode;
```

will point to a deleted node. As a result the pointer `*head` will be invalid.

That is after this statement

```
*head=newnode;
```

the both pointers `*head` and `newnode` point to the same one node. If you will write

```
free( newnode );
```

or

```
free( *head );
```

the pointed node will be deleted. So you nothing added to the list. What you was going to add to the list you deleted.:) And moreover you substituted a correct value in the pointer `*head` (before calling the function) for  an invalid value (address) that points nowhere after deleting the node.

Pay attention to that it would be more correct to define the function the following way

```
int push( struct node **head, int data )
{
    struct node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newnode->data = data;
        newnode->next = *head;

        *head = newnode;
    }

    return success;
}
```

In that case the function will not have undefined behavior when there is no enough memory to allocate a new node. And the user of the function can check whether adding a new node was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't do `free(newnode);` here because the new node is added to the list and therefore will be used later.

Also the variable `newnode` itself is (typically) allocated on the stack and will be freed automatically when exiting from the function, so you don't need to manyally free that.

Answer (score 0):

Because *head will refer the dead `newnode`. You have to free them in the end of the code.
Actually, you don't need to get `head` as double pointer.

Comment: " Actually, you don't need to get `head` as double pointer." Then what will you use instead of that? Something like `typedef struct node* pnode;`? Global variables? Note that functions arguments in C are copies of what are passed and modifications to them will not affect what are passed.

Comment: Just use struct node*.

Comment: single pointer is enough to refer a struct.

Comment: And return the new value for `head`?

Comment: Don't assign newnode into head, set head->next as newnode